# ytsdk:How to change default download location to External Storage

Tags: android

i am trying  to create video downloader using `ytsdk.`

> The isssue facing with `ytsdk` is , it takes internal storage as
>   defualt  download location for videos.

My Query is how to change download loaction to External Storage.

*I have tried following*
    ytsdk.setDownloadFolderPath(System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE")+"/downloads");

but it giving me same internal storage.

Answer (score 0):

Go through this page of Android documentation to understand about Storage system. It has the code snippet that will help you.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html